# Optimize displaying results with django-haystack RealTimeSignalProcessor

Tags: python, django, django-models, solr, django-haystack

I use `Django` as backend for my web-app and `django-haystack(with Solr)` for searching & displaying results.
I use the `RealTimeSignalProccessor` form `django-haystack` , but I have one problem:
 - I have an `Auction model` and `expires-(DateTimeField)`. When I'm displaying the results I'm doing it similar like e-bay (ex. Expires in: 1h 23m 5s ).
 The problem is that on the page that all Auctions are displayed, if you want to update the `Expires in` parameter on every time you visit this view (as I've read in the django-haystack documentation) , you'll have to use the `object.save()` method to update the Solr indexing database. But if I do that for 30 results everytime i go to that view where all auctions are listed , it's very slow and it's not efficient.
Is there any other solution ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind why you'd want to update the expires in-value? Wouldn't that be identical to ordering by DateTimeField asc for any values where expires is larger than utcnow()?

Comment: `Expires` is always larger than utcnow() , about the updating - i need to show the time left till the auction finishesh. Example: 2d 4h 3m  and on page refresh (change it to 2d 4h 2m  etc..). As i said via the `django-haystack` docs. you need to call the save() method on the object to update the parameters in Solr for it

Comment: Yes, but the 'expires in' part doesn't really need to be part of your database. Calculate it when retrieving it in your model or in your view. Updating x number of rows for each page view will lead to issues down the road.

Comment: Actually yes, I just need to have the `expiring_date` indexed. I can than calculate the time left. Don't know why I didn't do it like that ... anyways , post it as answer & I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to keep updating a `expires_in` field in your database - keep an `expires_at` with the time when the ad expires, and calculate the time left in your retrieval method in your model or in your view.

This way you'll avoid having to write more data to your database as traffic increases, and if the expiry date changes you won't run into a possible race condition if people are viewing the page at the same time while you're updating the expiry time.